# How do I group and subtotal repeat values in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that uses apex:repeat to display a list of data returned by this query:

```
SELECT sirenum__Shift_Date__c, sirenum__Employee_Name__c, Actual_Length__c, Bill_Rate__c, Shift_Charge__c 
FROM sirenum__Shift__c 
WHERE sirenum__Client_ID__c =: clientId 
AND sirenum__Allow_charge__c = true 
AND sirenum__Shift_Date__c >=: cycleStartDate AND sirenum__Shift_Date__c <=: cycleEndDate  
ORDER BY sirenum__Shift_Date__c
```

I'd like to have the list appear grouped by Shift Date and subtotaled by Shift Charge for each group. How might I accomplish that?

Here's how my Visualforce page is currently structured:

```
<tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!shiftsInDateOrder}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item.sirenum__Shift_Date__c}" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item.sirenum__Employee_Name__c}" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-align--right">
                <div>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item.Actual_Length__c}"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-align--right" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <div>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item.Bill_Rate__c}"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-align--right">
                <div>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item.Shift_Charge__c}"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Like with many things, this simply means you need to create an appropriate data structure (here by date) that holds the data in a way that is easy for the VF markup to iterate and render. This is the same approach you need in LWC. So query the data then massage it into your date-based structure that you add totals to and subsequently iterate in the markup.

Comment: Thank you for that information, @PhilW. I'm hoping I can get some more detailed guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding something like the following to your controller:

1. A nested Apex class called `DatedShifts` or similar that includes these properties:

   1. `Date forDate`.
   2. `List<sirenum__Shift__c> shifts`.
   3. `Double subtotal`.
2. Provide a `List<DatedShifts> shiftsByDate` property that can be requested and iterated by the page markup.
3. Get the data back from your query and iterate it:

   1. If the last processed date (initialized to null outside the iteration) is different to the current shift date (sirenum__Shift_Date__c) then create a new DatedShifts instance and add it to the `shiftsByDate`, using the current shift's date for it.
   2. Add the current shift to the DatedShifts instance `shifts`.
   3. Update the DatedShifts instance `subtotal` however you need to.
4. Update your Visualforce markup to fetch and iterate the `shiftsByDate`:

   1. Render a section or similar with the `forDate` value.
   2. Fetch and iterate the `shifts` to render each shift.
   3. Render the `subtotal` however you need.

Note that point 3.1 works because you already order the results by date, so just looking for a change in date is enough to know you need to create a new "current DatedShifts" instance and add it to the data to be rendered.

Here are the pieces of code you would likely need to address this. Firstly, the nested class with an easy-to-use constructor:

```
class DatedShifts {
    public Date forDate {get; set;}
    public List<sirenum__Shift__c> shifts {get; set;}
    public Double subtotal {get; set;}
    
    public DatedShifts(Date forDate) {
        this.forDate = forDate;
        this.shifts = new List<sirenum__Shift__c>();
        this.subtotal = 0;
    }
}
```

The controller then needs to expose the `shiftsByDate` list for use in your page markup:

```
public List<DatedShifts> shiftsByDate = new List<DatedShifts>();
```

In the controller code that performs the existing query, update that code like:

```
List<sirenum__Shift__c> shiftsInDateOrder = [
        SELECT Id, Billing_Line__c, sirenum__Shift_Date__c, sirenum__Contact__c, sirenum__Employee_Name__c,
                Actual_Length__c, Bill_Rate__c, Comments_formatted__c,
                Shift_Charge__c
                FROM sirenum__Shift__c
                WHERE sirenum__Client_ID__c = :clientId
                        AND sirenum__Allow_charge__c = TRUE
                        AND sirenum__Shift_Date__c >= :cycleStartDate
                        AND sirenum__Shift_Date__c <= :cycleEndDate
                        AND (sirenum__Rota__r.Name = :category
                                OR sirenum__Team__r.sirenum__Rota__r.Name = :category)
                ORDER BY sirenum__Shift_Date__c, Job_Type_Sort_Order__c, sirenum__Employee_Name__c
];
Date lastShiftDate = null;
DatedShifts current = null;

for (sirenum__Shift__c shift : shiftsInDateOrder) {
    // I assume the shift's date is always defined (never null)
    if (lastShiftDate != shift.sirenum__Shift_Date__c) {
        lastShiftDate = shift.sirenum__Shift_Date__c;
        current = new DatedShifts(lastShiftDate);
        shiftsByDate.add(current);
    }

    current.shifts.add(shift);
    current.subtotal += shift.Shift_Charge__c;
}
```

At this point the controller's `shiftsByDate` is fully populated with a sequence of `DatedShifts` records, in date order.

The VF page markup must first iterate `shiftsByDate`, getting the entry for a given date. This entry provides the `forDate` to render in a section/page block and the list of `shifts` to iterate to render for that date, plus the `subtotal`.

The updated VF rendering probably wants to be something like the following:

```
<tbody>
    <!--
     ! Iterate over the dated shifts, outputting a date heading, the shifts
     ! then the date's subtotal.
     !-->
    <apex:repeat value="{!shiftsByDate}" var="dated">
        <!--
         ! The table has 5 columns, so the date header row needs to span
         ! them all.
         !-->
        <tr><th colspan="5"><apex:outputText value="{!dated.forDate}"/></th></tr>

        <!--
         ! Now iterate the shifts.
         !-->
        <apex:repeat value="{!dated.shifts}" var="shift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!shift.sirenum__Shift_Date__c}" />
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!shift.sirenum__Employee_Name__c}" />
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="text-align--right">
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!shift.Actual_Length__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="text-align--right" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!shift.Bill_Rate__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="text-align--right">
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!shift.Shift_Charge__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>

        <!--
         ! Finally output the subtotal for this date.
         !-->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="text-align--right">Subtotal:</th>
            <th class="text-align--right"><apex:outputText value="{!dated.subtotal}"/></th>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

I used `th` for the date and subtotal rows just to ensure they are formatted differently (default would be bold), but `td` and styling classes could be used instead.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to consider how to [format the date heading and the subtotal value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm), if the default output isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, Phil, for that guidance. I now have steps 1 & 2 coded. 
Can you provide additional guidance on coding steps 3 & 4?

Comment: Updated the answer. I cannot help specifically with 4 as I don't know how you have structured your VF page.

Comment: That update was very helpful, Phil - thank you. My controller now includes all your suggestions.

My original post above is now updated to include details about subtotaling and my VF page structure. Any additional guidance you can give on implementing item 4 from your answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RobAlexander updates provided. Please note that this isn't really the sort of service normally provided by SFSE. Please look at [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) at the best way to ask questions. We look for some effort by the asker to solve their own problem, showing research or failed code snippets. It is not normal for us to provide solutions to requirements like this, which is why your question got closed.